# Next js data fetching with axios instance and Authorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

I'm using NextJS `12.0.10` with next-redux-wrapper `7.0.5`
And Axios custom instance to hold user JWT token saved in local storage and inject it with every request also to interceptors incoming error's in each response

The problem with this is that I simply cannot use the Axios instance inside the Next data fetching methods

Because there is no way to bring user JWT Token from local storage when invoking the request inside the server
Also, I cannot track the request in case of failure and send the refresh token quickly

I tried to use cookies but `getStaticProps` don't provide the req or resp obj
Should I use `getServerSideProps` always

---

### **axios.js**

```js
  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    timeout: 20000,
    headers: {
      common: {
        Authorization: !isServer()
          ? localStorage.getItem("access_token")
            ? "JWT " + localStorage.getItem("access_token")
            : null
          : null,
        accept: "application/json",
      },
    },
  });
```

### login-slice.js

```js
  export const getCurrentUser = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/getCurrentUser",
    async (_, thunkApi) => {
      try {
        const response = await axiosInstance.get("api/auth/user/");
        await thunkApi.dispatch(setCurrentUser(response.data));
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.response.data) {
          return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
        toast.error(error.message);
  
        return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error.message);
      }
    }
  );
```

### Page.jsx

```js
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps((store) => async (ctx) => {
  try {
    await store.dispatch(getCurrentUser());
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("here", e);
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
});
```

Comment: you can choose next-redux-cookie-wrapper to bring client state to ssr

Answer (score 0):

Server side rendered technology is a one-way street if you follow the standard practise. You won't get any local details - being it cookies, local store or local states back to the server.

I would let the server build the DOM as much as it makes sense (ie with empty user data) and let the client fetch the data via useEffect.

Comment: This will eliminate some of the features I used Next for, I think the best solution is to deal with the session via cookies, that's what I trying to do right now